# android:layout_alignBottom not working for API 18 and below?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Need some enlightenment if this is different Android version issue (v18 SDK and before).

Below is the layout we have, in particular the `txt_subitem` should be align bottom of `img_picture`. The code below works fine for v19 and later (since Kit-Kat), but not for v18, as shown in picture beneath.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/img_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_picture"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:src="#0f0"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_subitem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/img_picture"
        android:text="testing"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/img_picture"
        android:background="#00f"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The below shows what v19 SDK display. E.g. the blue color is aligned with the green box, which is expected due to `android:layout_alignBottom="@id/img_picture"`
[image: v18]

However, for v18 SDK and before (tested on v17 and v16 through emulator and real devices), the image is layout where the blue color box is not aligned as expected, but alignment extend to the margin (20dp) of `@+id\img_picture`.

[image: v19]

Could someone shed some light if this is the Android v18 SDK issue or I have missed something. Thanks!

Comment: Remove the **+** sign from `@+id/img_picture`

Comment: Removed the + sign, result the same as before... the TextView still overshoot the ImageView for v18 SDK and below :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For API 18 and earlier, the margin is being applied after the alignment so if the margin in the ImageView is greater than 0 you will get your textview moved. You can check this setting the margin to 0.

If you want to add a margin from his parent, try this:

- Keeping `android:layout_margin="20dp"`, add `android:layout_marginTop="10dp"` to your TextView
- Not keeping `android:layout_margin="20dp"`, use padding in the parent view (like the example).

  ```
  <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/img_container"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:padding="20dp">

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/img_picture"
          android:layout_width="100dp"
          android:layout_height="80dp"
          android:src="#0f0"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/txt_subitem"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignBottom="@id/img_picture"
          android:layout_alignLeft="@id/img_picture"
          android:text="testing"
          android:background="#00f"/>

  </RelativeLayout>
  ```

Comment: Declaring the TextView first will put the TextView behind the ImageView :(. Removing the "+" while the TextView is before the ImageView result in compilation error :(.

Comment: Thanks @Alberto. This will work and it was my workaround as well. But it still doesn't explain why when the padding is in the "ImageView", the alignBottom doesn't work for v18 SDK and earlier, which I'm seeking.

Comment: @Elye Edited. Hope it helps you to understand the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Alberto. This helps. In short, it's indeed a limitation of v18 and before. v19 has corrected the issue. Up vote to you. Your answer is the best thus far. "Tick' to your answer. Thanks!!

Comment: @Elye No problem, up vote to your question too for the weird error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87989/discussion-between-elye-and-alberto-fernandez).

Answer (score 3):

@Courtesy to Frank N. Stein

```
  <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/img_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_picture"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:src="#0f0"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_subitem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/img_picture"
            android:text="testing"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/img_picture"
            android:background="#00f"

            />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Removing the "+" sign result the same for v18 SDK and below. Where the txt_subitem still overshoot where it supposed to be :(

Answer (score 0):

you can use FrameLayout instead of RelativeLayout. that will suitable for your requirement.In FrameLayout you can move your TextView with simply using gravity.

Comment: Thanks user3202237. I've already have workaround the issue. I'm just seeking for clarification if anyone already know this as a real limitation.